# plot different lines in different colors based on a property they have

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot some lines with different orientation on a 2d surface.
For each line I have a number inside a list based on a property I am checking, so if I have 2 lines that share that property thay will have the same color.
How do I do that?
The code I have, doesnt seem to work that way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm


def line(x,y,ang):
    a=[]
    for i in range(len(ang)):
        a.append(np.deg2rad(ang[i]))
    Xmax=[]
    Ymax=[]
    Xmin=[]
    Ymin=[]
    L=100           
    for i in range(len(x)):
        Xmax.append(x[i]+L*np.sin(a[i]))
        Ymax.append(y[i]+L*np.cos(a[i]))
        Xmin.append(x[i]-L*np.sin(a[i]))
        Ymin.append(y[i]-L*np.cos(a[i]))
    X=[Xmin,Xmax]
    Y=[Ymin,Ymax]
    return X, Y



#my data for the lines
ang=[210,291,226,350,217,220,331]
lat=[32.7338,31.5918,32.2529,33.0827,30.1177,29.79329,32.6217]
lon=[35.1918,35.3933,35.526,35.1741,34.7257,34.9152,34.9862]



#the properties of the lines
rect=[0.899,0.845,0.97,0.4,0.48,0.65,0.77]



#the colors i want the lines to have
colors=('r-','g-','y-','m-','c-','b','k-')


#the center of the plot
av_lat=np.average(lat)
av_lon=np.average(lon)

#XX and YY are arrays that contain 2 points in each ax, for a given number of lines
XX,YY=line(lon,lat,ang)

#not important
rows=2
columns=2
xav=np.average(lon)
yav=np.average(lat)
xr=np.arange(xav-columns,xav+columns,0.01)
yr=np.arange(yav-rows,yav+rows,0.01)


####i am trying to give each line a color based on one of the propertys above
col=[]
R=max(rect)
for i in range(len(rect)):
    if rect[i]<=0.5:
        col.append(colors[0])
    elif rect[i]<=0.8:
        col.append(colors[1])
    elif rect[i]<=0.82:
        col.append(colors[2])
    elif rect[i]<=0.84:
        col.append(colors[3])
    elif rect[i]<=0.86:
        col.append(colors[4])
    elif rect[i]<=0.88:
        col.append(colors[5])
    else:
        col.append(colors[6])


plt.figure(1)
axes = plt.gca()
plt.plot(lon,lat,'ko')
axes.set_ylim([yr[0], yr[len(yr)-1]]) ; axes.set_xlim([xr[0], xr[len(xr)-1]])
plt.plot(XX,YY,c=col)  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<how do i give the lines i have, a color based on propertys they have
#plt.savefig('lines.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: it is better to ask with a minimal example, and to provide data to run an example.

Comment: I edited the script and gave it some data so now it works.

Comment: Okay, thanks - there was still too much noise and un-necessary stuff so I simplified it to give you an example of what I would do to address a problem like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that does what you want after removing the noise and building fake data:

It takes the slope of the line and assigns a color based on the sign and value of that slope. Of course, this is a bit contrived, but refactoring the calculation of the condition and the assignment of the color to different portions of code makes it easy to understand, maintain, modify and adapt.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

import random

def slope(x, y):
    return (y[0] - y[1]) / (x[0] - x[1])

def get_color(condition):
    if condition < 0:
        if abs(condition) < 1:
            return 'red'
        else:
            return 'green'
    else:
        if abs(condition) < 1:
            return 'blue'
        else: return 'cyan'

XX = [(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in range(12)]
YY = [(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in range(12)]


plt.figure(1)
for x, y in zip(XX, YY):
    color = get_color(slope(x, y))

    plt.plot(x ,y, linewidth=3, color=color)
plt.show()
```

In this example, 12 lines segments are plotted; those that have negative slope are `red` or `green`, with the steepest `green`; the positive slopes are `blue` or `cyan` with the steepest `cyan`

[image]